# regular expression for matching a specific decimal number

Tags: regex

I need to verify if the answer entered by a user is correct for an online quiz.

The answer is supposed to be a decimal number that may be entered in a number of different ways. For example,

```
0.666666...
```

could match

```
.66
.67
.66666
.667
0.6667
```

etc.

Basically, I want to ignore rounding, precision, and preceding zeros. The examples I found are for matching any decimal numbers.

thanks,

RT

edits -

I am writing a quiz for WebCT. It allows three options for matching correct answer: "equals", "contains" and "regular expression". I believe WebCT is Java based. But I couldn't be sure as to what flavor of regular-expression it uses. I can ask users to provide correct answer upto three decimal places. In which case correct answers could be one of the following four:
0.666
0.667
.666
.667

Comment: *Why* a regular expression? Why? Rather tell us what language you're using and we'll give you the sensible answer.

Comment: What language? And why do you need a regex? It's not something a regex would be perfect for.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Regular expressions are purely textual and have no notion of "a decimal number that may be expressed in a number of different ways"

Comment: RE matching knows nothing about numbers, it simply matches text. Why couldn't you match a string as being a valid numeric string, convert it to floating point, and then compare arithmetically using a delta range around the desired value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off simply converting the user-entered string into a number (using whatever language facilities you have, lke C's `atof`), then just ensuring it's close enough (within a set margin of error), or even by specifying a minimum and maximum (say 0.6 and 0.67).

But, if you *really* want a regex:

```
^0*\.6+7?$
```

should do the trick for that particular number.

That's zero of more of `0` followed by `.`, then one or more `6` characters and an optional `7`.

To enforce at least two decimal places as requested in a comment, you could use:

```
^0*\.6+[67]$
```

That forces it to end in a `6` or `7` and have one or more `6` characters preceding that.

Comment: While this is a fairly reasonable approach I'm not totally sure that I agree. If the question is "What are the first few digits in the decimal representation of two thirds?" and someone writes "0.66666091" I'm not actually sure that should be marked correct, despite it being quite close. Your approach would accept this, but they obviously haven't understood the basic principles of repeating decimals.

Comment: Super. it works!! The answer does not have to precise. Is there a way to enforce "at least" two decimal places: correct - .66,.67. incorrect .6.  thanks a lot,rt

Comment: Is there any way to avoid square brackets?? webCT requires that the answer be enclosed in square-brackets [], and complains about nested brackets [^0*\.6+[67]$]. thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `^0*\.66+7?$` which gives you almost the same effect but that limitation seems a little arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

For a decimal representation of a fraction, you have a nice normal form: it will consist of a finite decimal, followed by a sequence of decimal digits that repeat infinitely.  So, e.g., 1/7 is "0." followed by infinitely many repetitions of "142857".  There's a sense (see below) in which these fractional decimal representations are the only ones that can be represented by a regular expression.

The technique for these is that you represent these with a tree, where the base part is a series of optional bracketed expressions, with alternatives to express rounding up so 8.19 would be given `8(.(2|(19?)?)?`, and then repeating part starred, and then a section that gives all the ways that the repeating part may be rounded.

E.g.: 1/7 is given by `0?.(142857)*(1(4(3|2(8(6|57?)?)?)?)?)?`.

#### Aside

The sense in which regular expressions can express only fractions is the following.  Say that a formal expression describes a decimal representation if its language is all the finite decimal prefixes of the number, so an expression for 2/3 must have as its language 0, 0.6, 0.66, 0.666, &c.  A finite state machine that accepts only prefixes in this way must repeat itself, and thus be a fraction.

So no regular expression accepts, say `sqrt(2)` exactly.

Comment: Hi Charles, Your answer helped solve a more general problem than the one i had originally posted. Thanks, RT

Comment: @user151410: My answer doesn't explain how to treat carries (basically, whenever a 9 is followed by a 5-9), so there's a tricky case, where, e.g., 1.00000 and 0.9999 are approximations to the same number, which has two different recurring decimals, 1+0/9 or 0+9/9.  I might add that later, if there's interest.

Answer (score 1):

`/^0*\.6+7?\.*$/`

Broken down:

`^0*` <- optional zeroes

`\.` <- escaped decimal

`6+` <- at least one 6, or more

`7?` <- optional 7

`\.*$` <- ellipsis, at least 0 or more

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the explanation. it is easier to learn something in the context of your own problem.  rt

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you want regular expressions for this. They are purely textual and have no notion of "decimal numbers that can be expressed in more than one way."

I think what you should do is convert the user's answer to a floating-point data type in whatever programming language you're working in, and subtract it from the correct answer. The result is the error in the student's answer. If the result is less than some threshold, say +0.06, then consider it correct. That way, 0.6, 0.66, 0.667, 0.6667, etc., will all be considered correct.